# element in form is empty in IE

Tags: php, javascript, forms

The following code is working in FF but not in IE. There is no value of `document.myform["parameters"].value` in IE.

The code:

```
function form_elements()
{
   if(document.myform.elements["parameters"].value == '')
    {
       myform_values = ......
    }
}

 <form method="post" name="myform">
  <div id="parameters_info">
    <select id="parameters" name="parameters" onfocus="e =form_elements();" >
        <?php
            foreach($params_name as $name)
              {
                if($name == $param_posted)
              {
                  echo "<option selected>$name</option>";
              }
              else
              {
                  echo "<option>$name</option>";
              }
            }

        ?>
      </select>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried also `document.myform["parameters"].value` but the value is empty.

My options are like:

```
<option>1234</option>
<option>234a</option>
```

And i want that the value of the option will be in the function.

10x,
Ronny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a value to each option. Also, you cannot get the selected option using the value of the select tag. You need to use:

```
var selectedOption = document.myform.parameters.options[document.myform.parameters.options.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<option>1234</option>`
`1234` - is a `text` of an option.
`<option value="1234">1234</option>`
Now `1234` - is a text and value.

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
document.forms["myform"].elements["parameters"].options[document.forms["myform"].elements["parameters"].selectedIndex].text
```

...or you can use a function like this, which returns an array of values from any field type:

```
function getFieldValueArray(fld, frm) {
   // fld may be a field object or a field name
   // frm may be an index or a name, defaults to document.forms[0] when needed and not supplied
   //function returns an array of values
   var form = frm ? document.forms[frm] : document.forms[0];
   var field = (typeof(fld) == "object") ? fld : form.elements[fld];
   var valueArray = new Array();
   var multinode = (field.length>1) ? true : false;
   var type = field.type;
   if (!type) {
      type = field[0].type;
      }
   switch(type) {
      case "radio": //fall-through intentional
      case "checkbox":
         if (multinode) {
            for (i=0; i<field.length; i++) {
               if (field[i].checked) {
                  valueArray.push(field[i].value);
                  }
               }
            }
         else {
            if (field.checked) {
               valueArray.push(field.value);
               }
            }
         break;
      case "select-one": //fall-through intentional
      case "select-multiple":
         var options = field.options;
         for (i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].selected) {
               valueArray.push(options[i].value ? options[i].value : options[i].text);
               }
            }
         break;
      case "text": //fall-through intentional
      case "file":
         valueArray.push(field.value);
         break;
      case "hidden":
         valueArray = field.value.split(";");
         break;
      case "textarea":
         valueArray = field.value.split("\n");
      default:
         alert("Field not found -- atGetField(" + fld.toString() + ")");
      }
   return valueArray;
   }
```

The function comes in rather handy when you can't be certain what type the field may be (for instance, if the field is an editable type under some circumstances and hidden under others), but once written it's an easy fallback, particularly for selects, radios and checkboxes.